# Trying to use free() to understand how it works

Tags: c, debugging, pointers, malloc, free

To understand the usage of free in the C programming language I tried running this code on Ubuntu, but on running the EXE file I am receiving a SIGABRT error. Why is the program not exiting normally?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int ret;
   int *ptr;
   ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
   free(ptr);
   ptr = &ret;
   free(ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: static allocation automatically reclaimed.Not require to `free` it.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: You never pass to `free` a value that was not returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, or a function that returns you a pointer to memory allocated 'as if' allocated by one of these functions (e.g. `strdup()`, `getline()`, `asprintf()`, `scanf()` with the `%ms` modifier, etc).

Comment: How did you get and run, an `EXE` file on Ubuntu?

Comment: compiling using g++ creates the .exe file that you can use to run the code.
For example: 
g++ -g abc.cpp -o out;

here out is the name of exe file created (if you don't use -o and give name like out or something by default a.out is created)
-g is for debugging on gdb.

Comment: `free` is the "un-malloc" function, not the "free any memory" function.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Attempting to free a pointer you didn't get from `malloc` (or one of its friends) causes undefined behaviour.  Your second `free(ptr)` call attempts just that.

From the C spec, **§7.22.3.3 The `free` function**, paragraph 2:

> The **`free`** function causes the space pointed to by **`ptr`** to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If **`ptr`** is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to **`free`** or **`realloc`**, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 11):

```
   ptr = &ret;
   free(ptr);
```

is the same as:

```
    free(&ret);
```

`ret` resides on the stack, not on the heap.  Attempting to `free()` memory that was not allocated (with `malloc()`, etc.) on the heap will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: In every case I am familiar with, it will cause a run-time error.

Comment: @RiaD:  every platform I've worked on will give a runtime error.  But platforms aren't required to (e.g., very constrained embedded systems that run without an OS), and undefined behavior is widely misunderstood ( http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 ), it means something very different from "your operating system will complain."

Comment: @MaxLybbert, well, my comment addressed "will cause a run-time error" line in the answer which is now edited out

Comment: I knew the answer had been around for a while, and I wasn't expecting an answer from either you or @MahonriMoriancumer.  I simply want to get the word out that "undefined behavior" means a lot more than "sudden crash."  It could mean "the compiler changes your code, and the end result may not even be describable in the original language."

Answer (score 11):

While all the the undefined behavior answers are correct, seeing an implementation might be more helpful.

I think a very good reference to this is [K&R C malloc](https://code.google.com/r/nizchka-ruda/source/browse/history/krmalloc.c?r=4cc0882c49b0e6cd6b1b32ace5c0b683e455341b). An explanation of how it works is in ["The C Programming Langugage"](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs101/2008/resource/The_C_Programming_Language.pdf), Chapter 8.7.

Remember when looking at code from standard library functions in C that they have an implementation and a specification, where the implementation might have reproducible behavior that is not required by its specification.

Essentially almost all `malloc` implementations have a free list where they manage free memory regions in a list (or multiple lists). The free list is often handled in a way, that calling `free` on a memory region multiple times will put this list in an incorrect state.

Also malicious behavior can be invoked when data structures are purposefully crafted. [Phrack](http://phrack.org/issues/57/9.html) has a dated article on how to invoke code execution when passing invalid memory to `free` while corrupting the freelist.

[Other malloc implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Implementations) might also be worth looking at (this is an incomplete list of allocation libraries).

Answer (score 9):

The function `free()` only works for the memory that has been allocated on `heap` by `malloc()`. Not for the static allocation, because static allocations are automatically handled. Here is the mistake:

```
 int ret; 

 ptr = &ret;

 free(ptr);
```

You can't do this because the memory for `ret` is not allocated on the heap. It's in the stack and only the memory of the heap should be freed.

Answer (score 8):

Your second `free(ptr)` is causing undefined behavior as you are attempting to free a pointer which you didn't allocate. Also note that static allocations are automatically reclaimed, so you don't require them to free it.

Answer (score 5):

```
  ptr = &ret;
   free(ptr);
```

Here you are trying to free the local storage stack variable's memory. As per rule you should not free it. When the main() exits all local storage memory on stack always get free.

Free only works with Heap allocation memory.

Answer (score 2):

There are three areas where variables may be created in a c or c++ program.

- global or static variables are at fixed locations in the executable binary file.
- automatic variables outside of static scope are on the stack
- malloc'ed or calloc'ed variables are on the heap.

free() is the function that releases previously allocated memory on the heap. A pointer to memory on the heap is returned by malloc or similar functions. The only way to read or write that memory is via the pointer. A pointer is an address, and a pointer* is the content pointed to at that address.

In the example shown, there are two variables, defined in Main, and effectively static, and the returned value from Main, which is on the stack. Using the miniumum int, 16 bits, here's a possible memory map. In this map, the instructions start at 0, the stack starts at some non-zero value, (beginning of stack - bos) and grows by incrementing, and a heap starts at the maximum address (...FFFF, aka -1) and grows by decrememeting:

(Remember, MIN_INT is -32768, MAX_INT is 32767... the spec guarantees only 16 bits, signed)

Each byte has an address which is 'n' bits wide - 16, 32 or 64 bits, typically

---

-1.  (start of heap, for example, 16 bit addr: 0xFFFF, 32 bit addr: 0xFFFFFFFF or 64 bit addr: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)

-2. (1st location down from beginning of heap. 0x...FFFE)  ptr[ 9 ], at one time

-3. (2nd location down from beginning of heap. 0x...FFFD)

-4. (3rd location down from beginning of heap. 0x...FFFC)  ptr[ 8 ], at one time

[snip]

-17. (16th location down from beginning of heap. 0x...FFEF)

-18. (17th location down from beginning of heap. 0x...FFEE)  ptr[ 1 ], at one time

-19. (18th location down from beginning of heap. 0x...FFED)

-20 (19th location down from beginning of heap. 0x...FFEC)  ptr[ 0 ], at one time

-21. (top of heap, 10 X 16 bit ints down from beginning of heap. 0x...FFEB), at one time

:
A very large range of address on 32 or 64 bit machines...
:

tos: ( Top of stack 0x...tos )

bos + ( sizeof( int ) - 1)  End of int returned from Main()

bos: (beginning of stack: above static data )   Start of int returned from Mail()

togs: (top of global/static) End of "ptr"

:        (size of a pointer is width of address bus... whatever it takes)

togs-(n-1): (top of global/static - (sizeof( int* ) - 1)) start of "ptr"

(togs-n) : End of "ret"

(togs-n)-1: start of "ret"

(any global stuff the compiler adds for itself, the debugger, etc.)

(end of program code)

(start of program code)

(top of non-program code)

0 (start of non-program code, 0x...0000 )

---

At run-time, "ptr" and "ret" are probably both start at '0', since they're fixed, static, values, read out of the file the executable binary comes from.

As the program runs, the value of "ptr" changes, first, to point into the heap, at the malloc'ed array of 10 ints: "0x...FFEC"

The call to free() doesn't change the value of ptr, its still "0x...FFEC"
Free'ing "0x...FFEC" is legit and runs without anything funny.

The assignment "ptr = &ret" sets a new value into "ptr", "(togs-n)-1", the start of "ret".

Free'ing "(togs-n)-1" causes an immediate crash because "free" checks the value of "(togs-n)-1" and it is NOT in the valid range for a heap address.

"ret" remains blank, its never set, but since its global/static, it remains at whatever it was when the linker wrote it to disk.